# Runnable jar does nothing,resources not exporting

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource

I have created a media player, when I run it in eclipse it works fine[image: mediaPlayer]

but when I export a runnable jar and try to run, it does nothing.. may be because the images that are in resource folder are not being exported while creating the jar, when I run it using "java -jar" command the jar file runs but the image icon is not there[image]

```
      playIcn = new ImageIcon("Resources/play.png");
      pauseIcn = new ImageIcon("Resources/pause.png");
      stopIcn = new ImageIcon("Resources/stop.png");
```

creating icon using this code.

any suggestions ??

Comment: aren't you getting exceptions? If you are getting please post them here. Also how are you exporting classes and resources to the jar?

Comment: am just exporting the runnable jar(using the, package required liberaries into jar, if that is what you are asking) .. what do I have to do to export the resources ??  and I was not getting any exceptions before .. but when I used " playIcn = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Resources/play.png"));"   I got null pointer exception java.swing.imageicon

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream('file-name')`. In eclipse it will take path as relative to your class that is why it is working.

In your case `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Resource/image1.jpeg")` this might help.

Comment: it says  .."constructor ImageIcon(InputStream) is undefined

Comment: I tried using  playIcn = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Resources/play.png"))   .. it throws null pointer exception

Comment: try using `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/Resources/play.png")`

Comment: @AkashGajbhiye Try changing `ImageIcon` constructor to accept `InputStream` instead of `String` or `File`.

Comment: stopIcn = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Images/stop.png")));

Comment: if I export a JAR .. not "runnable jar" then the resource folder is exported(I extracted the jar file) .. but then the external libraries are not exported

Comment: @AkashGajbhiye to avoid all these jar problems, use `maven` which will automatically does jar packaging. Follow this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-java-project-with-maven/

Comment: @AkashGajbhiye Otherwise put all jar files in `lib` directory and configure the `build path` in eclipse to jars in lib then generate jar

Comment: I did build path .. everything is working fine there are no exceptions .. the only problem now is that when I double click on the jar it does nothing .. when I run the jar using "java -jar" it works fine .. without any problems(even icons are also visible)

Comment: As per my knowledge you can select `main class` (staring class of your app) while generating `jar`. I dont know which will work on Double click.